# Making web scraper yield more information

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have written a simple web scraper that extracts street names and the serial number of that street from addresses and zip codes that I have in a `csv` file. I want to save the street name, the serial number, and the zip code in a new `csv` file, but I don't know how to pass the zip code to my `parse()` method, since I call the spider from `cmd` through:

```
scrapy crawl Geospider -o Scraped_data.csv -t csv
```

This is my spider (the code actually won't work since the page I'm scraping requires login and password, and I won't provide mine, but anyone can sign up as a user on http://download.kortforsyningen.dk//content/opret-mig-som-bruger, and it's not part of my problem):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import csv

class Road(Item):
    RoadNum = Field()
    RoadName = Field()
    PostNum = Field()

class Geospider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'Geospider'
    allowed_domains = ["http://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/"]

    def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        for row in csv_reader:
            yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

    filename = 'AddressesAndZipcodes.csv'
    reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
    start_urls = []
    ZipCode = []
    for row in reader:
        Address = row[0]
        Zip = row[1]
        start_urls.append('http://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/service?ServiceName=geoV&soegemetode=0&vejnavn=%s&kommunepost=%s&format=XML&max_hits=10&login=xxx&password=xxx' % (Address, ZipCode))
        ZipCode.append(Zip)

    def parse(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = xxs.select('//dokument/forekomst')
        items = Road()
        items['RoadNum'] = sites.select("vejkode/text()").extract()
        items['RoadName'] = sites.select("vejnavn/text()").extract()
        items['PostNum'] = ZipCode
        yield items, ZipCode
```

Any thoughts on how to pass ZipCode to `Parse()` so that the zipcodes are saved along with the other results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding `start_requests`, reading csv file there and passing `zip` in the `request.meta` will work for you:

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import csv


class Road(Item):
    RoadNum = Field()
    RoadName = Field()
    PostNum = Field()


def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]


class Geospider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'Geospider'
    allowed_domains = ["http://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/"]
    start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        reader = unicode_csv_reader(open('AddressesAndZipcodes.csv'))
        for row in reader:
            address, zip_code = row[:2]
            url = 'http://kortforsyningen.kms.dk/service?ServiceName=geoV&soegemetode=0&vejnavn=%s&kommunepost=%s&format=XML&max_hits=10&login=xxx&password=xxx' % (address, zip_code)

            yield Request(url=url, meta={'zip_code': zip_code})

    def parse(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = xxs.select('//dokument/forekomst')

        item = Road()
        item['RoadNum'] = sites.select("vejkode/text()").extract()
        item['RoadName'] = sites.select("vejnavn/text()").extract()
        item['PostNum'] = response.meta['zip_code']

        yield item
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: See also http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions for how to use request.meta and special keys recognized by Scrapy.